# createWindowSurface failed EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED when screen is turned on

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, egl

I am getting this exception randomly when screen is turned on:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: createWindowSurface failed EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:1349)
    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createEglSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:1241)
    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:1058)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1875)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6630)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why is this happening and is there some api to check if `EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED`, that way I can delay starting the activity.

( this happens mostly on samsung galaxy tab 4 10.1 SM-T530 )

Comment: I faced with the exact same problem on Nexus 7 2013 (Razor), Android OS 4.4.4. @jacob Did you have any additional info about this problem?